# Can a script in <head> load a css file async

Tags: javascript, html, css, asynchronous

Was looking for some ways to load a css file async in my application.
Currently I have a place holder that allows users to insert some extra
html in the head usually reserved for things like meta tags etc. If I put a script like this inside of `<head>` would it load the file async or would it block the render while its making the request.

```
<script>~function (document) {
  var elem = document.createElement('link');
  var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
  elem.rel = 'stylesheet';
  elem.href = 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cardo:700|Merriweather:400italic,400,700';
  elem.media = 'only x';
  head.appendChild(elem);
  setTimeout(function () {
    elem.media = 'all';
  });
}(document);</script>
```

Comment: Trial & error is your friend!

Comment: This is almost code review. :)  Your approach seems like it will work, because the "only x" will defer the loading until your timeout sets the media to a valid type.

Comment: Well looking at something like webpagetest.org or chrome inspector how would I be able to tell it is blocking? on my dev environment there is very little latency in loading the rest of the scripts

Comment: You can always just fetch the script with ajax and then add a style node to the DOM. It's a minor pain because the API is a little different between IE and other browsers, but it's not hard either way.

Comment: [LazyLoad](http://cdnjs.com/libraries/lazyload) - Tiny, dependency-free async JavaScript and CSS loader.